# Eliminating camera jitters caused by repositioning camera within defined bounds

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

This is the image of what I'm trying to achieve, in a 3D space. I want the object to follow my finger within the green zone, but stay on the edge of the green zone if I move my finger outside of it. I have achieved this with the code below, but when moving my finger around the red zone a lot of jitters and clipping occurs as the object keeps snapping back within it's bounds. The jitters I'm seeing are caused when holding my finger in the red zone out of the players circle bounds. Instead of being "stuck" in the bounds the player is trying to continue and then being positioned back within the bounds, causing jitters. I'm looking for a way to limit the movement of the player within the bounds without having to reset it's position. My main camera is attached to the moving object so it's important that I eliminate the jitters. How can I smooth this out?

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera movementCam;
    readonly float radius = 0.45f;
    readonly float speed = 3f;
    Ray firstTouchPos;
    Vector2 playerPos;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 targetPosition;
    readonly float followDelay = 20f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            firstTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            playerPos = transform.position;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
        {
            Ray currentTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 direction = currentTouchPos.origin - firstTouchPos.origin;
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Vector3.zero);
            targetPosition = distance >= radius ? (Vector3) . (direction.normalized * radius) : (Vector3)(playerPos + direction * speed);
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, followDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to do it in `LateUpdate` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is incorrectly clamping, a simple fix would be:

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        Ray currentTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 direction = currentTouchPos.origin - firstTouchPos.origin;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Vector3.zero);
        targetPosition = (Vector3)(playerPos + direction * speed);
        if (targetPosition.sqrMagnitude > radius * radius) //if our calculated position is greater than the radius...
            targetPosition = targetPosition.normalized * radius; //set our calculated position to be exactly on the radius.
    }
```

The jitter was caused by your object leaving the radius one frame, and on the next frame would be clamped back to the radius, only for it to attempt to move outside the radius again the next frame.

This way removes the ternary operator, which means it will behave consistently across frames, rather than switching between clamp and movement each frame.

**Here are some additional pieces of advice for this issue, once you fix the above problem:**

You should multiply speed and followDelay by time.deltaTime in order to smooth them across frames correctly.

You should probably apply your camera motion during LateUpdate() instead of Update(), LateUpdate() happens after all your updates happen, what can happen is during Update() objects can move around before and after your camera code is called, causing it to behave slightly inconsistently from frame to frame, applying the motion in LateUpdate() to the camera means your camera moves only when all your objects have 'settled' into place after their update, making it behave more consistently.

Additionally you're technically using Lerp() wrong here, it shouldn't cause jitter but it's not exactly how lerp should be used. Are you sure you don't want Vector3.MoveTowards() instead?

Comment: The direction in the first calculation is being used to align the position of the player along the outer edge of the bounds when the mouse is outside of it.  I have no issues moving the player within the bounds, and it does follow the mouse correctly when the mouse is outside the bounds.  The issue is that the way I'm keeping the player within the bounds is by simply repositioning it to radius distance in the direction of the mouse, causing jitters as it repositions itself each frame.  I think I need a better way to clamp it within the bounds but I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: You are correct about my misuse of Lerp and Update though.

Comment: Oh I understand a bit better now, let me re-phrase.

Comment: I've re-written my answer now I understand your actual problem.